# KOALA + FACEBOOK GRAPH gives FARADAY error (ConnectionFailed - Connection Refused - connect(2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am using koala(1.3.0) with rails (3.0.7).

This is how I use them.

Link to click function of facebook

```
<%= link_to 'Facebook Login', Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new.url_for_oauth_code(:callback => facebook_redirect_url), :class => "facebook_login" %>
```

This goes to following link

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.example.com%2Ffacebook%2Fredirect
```

Now I get the code in params in my facebook controller of redirect.
Following is what I do next in redirect method of facebook controller.

```
session[:access_token] = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(url_r).get_access_token(params[:code]) if params[:code]
```

but this line of code gives faraday ConnectionFailed error.

I am stuck at this point. Can't figure out what is the reason behind this.

I have also done the following with this another way also. 
After I get code in params

```
facebook_access_token_redirect_link = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=355***************&redirect_uri=#{url_i}&client_secret=MY_APP_SECRET&code=#{params[:code]}"
```

and redirect to this link. But then I get an error from facebook
***Error validating verification code***

I don't understand this also.

Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly thing. The server I was hosting my app at has banned all ***https connections***.

Removed that restriction and I got koala working.

Comment: i have the connection refused thing as well. Like that: "Connection refused - connect(2) for "*" port 443". I never had anything running on 443, and dont plan to. Also i never defined anywhere it should answer to there. Also it worked before with the very same code. I have no idea what kind of crazy BS this is.

Comment: My router's firewall started blocking koala suddenly as well, so my local machine wouldn't work with Facebook login. This answer led me to disabling the firewall and figuring out the issue. Thanks